# How exactly to interpret the output of this MatLab\Octave function calculating the value of a sigmoid function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, machine-learning, octave

I am studying a ML course on Coursera and I am pulling out some old linear algebra concept that I am not using since the time of university.

I have some doubts. I have this **MatLab\Octave** function that calculates the values of a sigmoid function:

```
g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-x));
```

Ok z could be:

1. A **SCALAR** value: for **x=0** it returns 0,5 because in 2 dimension x=0 --> the sigmoid function will return **y=0.5**

   ```
   g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(0));
   g
   g =  0.50000
   ```
2. A **VECTOR**:

   ```
   >> x = [1 2 3]
   x =
      1   2   3
   >> g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-x));
   >> g
   g =
      0.73106   0.88080   0.95257
   ```

Basically in this second example we are always in a 2 dimension example and I am calculating the values of Y in my the sigmoid function for 3 different values of X.

3. A **MATRIX**: here the situation changes because I have a matrix having multiple columns representing differnt features, to keep the example simple lets consider 2 features **X1** and **X2**:

   ```
   >> X = [1 2; 0 5]
   X =

      1   2
      0   5

   >> g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-X));
   >> g
   g =

      0.73106   0.88080
      0.50000   0.99331
   ```

Here I am finding some difficultis trying to understand how exactly interpret this situation.

In this case I have a matrix having 2 columns (the features **X1** and **X2**) so we are in a **three-dimensional** space, is it?

So the calculates values of g:

```
g =

       0.73106   0.88080
       0.50000   0.99331
```

the first column represent the values of the sigmoind function on the **X1** axis and the second column represents the values of the sigmoid function on the **X2** axis.

Is it or am I doing a big confusion?

If the previous reason is correct what it exaclty means? that this calculated **g** matrix reprents not mor a flat bidimensional sigmoid function but something like a three-dimensional function?

Comment: I took that course, and I'm trying to understand your question. Can you provide an example from Andrew Ng's course to illustrate your point?

Comment: Matlab/Octave is simply applying the sigmoid function separately on each of the entries of your matrix. Nothing more, nothing less. Notice that where the input matrix has a $0$ entry, the output has an entry $0.5$, because as you computed in the scalar case, $g(0) = 0.5$.